# HTTP failure callback for UrlFetchApp.fetch() in gmail addon

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail-addons

I would like to write a callback when a HTTP requests fails. How do I chain it to UrlFetchApp.fetch()?
 Please refer to the HTTP request below.

`// Make a GET request.
 UrlFetchApp.fetch('http://www.google.com/');`

Comment: `Try-catch`. `UrlFetch` is not executed asynchronously.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please note that the `fetch` function is synchronous. It does not provide a callback parameter and does not return a promise.

An approach to catching exceptions is possible through the `UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, params)` function. You can pass the `muteHttpExceptions` parameter into the params location of the function call. That way you can inspect the response code yourself and respond appropriately. Documentation: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app#fetchurl-params

```
UrlFetchApp.fetch('http://www.google.com/', {muteHttpExceptions: true});
```

> muteHttpExceptions (Boolean) if this is set to true, the fetch will not
>   throw an exception if the response code indicates failure, and will
>   instead return the HTTPResponse (default: false)

An alternative would be a simple try/catch statement. I imagine you could log the error or respond appropriately.

```
try {
   UrlFetchApp.fetch('http://www.google.com/');
}
catch(e) {
   // e contains error response
}
```